# iPhone 4 v. iPhone 5 Location Services Difference?

Tags: ios, core-location

I have an app that uses core location. It's primarily for iPad but it works on iPhone. I want to use the GPS but I don't want frequent updates. I have set it up like:

```
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init] ;
    locationManager.delegate = self ;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest ; // Enable GPS
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000 ; // One Kilometer
```

Some folks running the app on the iPhone 4 complain that it gets hot when the app is running. By that, they mean just sitting on the desk it gets hot.

On our iPhone 5's we see no differencing. In fact, we see nothing happening at all running. In the debugger, we see no GPS updates (as we'd expect) because we're not moving.

1. Is there a difference in behavior between the iPhone 4 and 5 in regard location services?
2. Should I be taking more drastic steps to conserve power?
3. Should I be taking less drastic steps to conserve power?
4. Could the GPS be consuming power in the background without the app having any activity?
5. Is there any documentation on how to push the device to GPS (I could increase the accuracy value to save power)?

I expect the iPad app to be used in locations with no wifi and no cell. I don't want it hunting for cell or wifi. At the same time I could live with 1000' accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to lower down you accuracy filter, i would set them like

```
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 500.0f;
```

And if that 1000m distance is not a hardcore requirement, then I would go for **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges** instead of **startUpdatingLocation**. As startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges usually appears after 1000m - 2000m of distance. It works pretty well on iPhone, not sure about the iPad (without cellular radio) as I believe it depends on wifi and cell towers.

Talking about iPhone 4 and 5 comparison, to my experience iPhone 4 (especially 4s) gets hot very quick as compared to iPhone 5. I have been working on location based apps for around 3 years and learned these tricks over the time.